# MessageBox.Show is not modal in the setup project

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, installation, setup-project

I have a VS2010 setup project, and one of it's uninstall custom actions shows notifications using MessageBox.Show method, but they sometimes appear to be behind the setup wizard window, which is totally unacceptable. Is there a way to show them on top of the wizard, maybe make them modal? Or should I create custom windows if it is impossible to show message boxes in a always-on-top or modal way?
I am not specifying any owners in the messagebox.show method.
The custom action calls a method of a class inside dll, not exe file.
I tried to find the process with name "msiexec" and mainwindowtitle == my setup project wizard window title, but in case of uninstall both processes just don't have any window titles and handles, although the uninstall window is displayed!

Comment: Presumably, the owner of the message box is the desktop window, which is why it's getting shown behind the wizard. What owner are you specifying in the `MessageBox.Show` function?

Comment: A comment beyond your initial question: you should avoid CA having its own UI. This is important if you have to support silent installations...

Comment: I am not specifying any owners in the messagebox function. What is CA?

Comment: CA stands for "custom action"

Comment: I am detecting situations when there is no UI (when the package is launched in quiet mode) and suppressing messages in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should use MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly in the MessageBox.Show method.

Comment: Is that possible to share the snippet? Showing how you did this...

Answer (score 1):

This works while installing or uninstalling on Windows XP and 7, as long as you have only one setup process going on:

```
        NativeWindow nativeWnd = new NativeWindow();
        try
        {
            IntPtr hWnd = (from p in Process.GetProcessesByName("msiexec") where p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero select p.MainWindowHandle).SingleOrDefault();
            if (hWnd == IntPtr.Zero)
                MessageBox.Show(message, title, buttons, icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
            else
            {
                nativeWnd.AssignHandle(hWnd);
                MessageBox.Show(nativeWnd, message, title, buttons, icon);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception thrown in ShowModalDlg", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
        }
        finally { nativeWnd.ReleaseHandle(); }
```

Comment: For me, it should be the right answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Inherited Form (Add new Windows Form -> Inherited Form)
or checkout the second constructor (IWin32Window) of MessageBox and assign the owner property. It displays a message box in front of the specified object.

Comment: What owner should I assign? How do I get the owner of the setup wizard?

Comment: do you call a dll or an exe-file?

Comment: The custom action calls dll .

Comment: Indeed, I had to get the setup process'es main window's handle and use it in my messagebox.show function: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/bbe69f12-8908-4c65-aa89-1963720d4c11

Answer (score 0):

It looks like during uninstall (and also repair), the setup is run by explorer.exe instead of msiexec.exe. So in the solution suggested [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/bbe69f12-8908-4c65-aa89-1963720d4c11), try looking for the setup window in "explorer" process, if it's not found in "msiexec". Note that unlike msiexec, in case of explorer the setup window is not the main window. So you will need to p/invoke [EnumWindows](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/EnumWindows.html) and [GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowThreadProcessId.html) to get the window.